# It's a Mad Mad Mad Mad World: Filibuster?

Tags: dialogue, its-a-mad-mad-mad-mad-world

Rewatching this 1963 film and at one point the dentist (Sid Caesar) says to Mickey Rooney's character, "Filibuster, filibuster..." -- this happens at the small airport right after the dentist and his wife have chartered the WW1 biplane.

I am assuming this relates to some earlier dialog (like when they were figuring the split of the money) that is on the cutting room floor but I can find nothing about this online.

What we see about the negotiations among the people about how much each is to receive is sort of summary -- we never see them talking about how the formulas were arrived at, that shares are based on number of cars, who went down, etc. but I suspect this complexity was in fact in the script and I am guessing that Mickey's character "filibusters" at some point during the discussion. I can understand deciding to cut most of the discussions out but that leaves the watcher of the movie mystified about "filibuster, filibuster." I guess this happens when a film is cut -- you forget sometimes that information is now missing. Or even you know that it is missing but there is no good way to fix subsequent scenes -- they could have then cut out the brief argument at the airport between the dentist and mickey's character but maybe they felt is was needed.

EDIT: BTW, there are scripts of this movie online but I suspect they are transcriptions of the film as it appeared so dialog that was cut would not show up in such a transcription. Anyway, I have not found the dialog which had to be early in the film in any script I have read through.

Comment: Can you give more context?

Comment: I haven't watched the movie in a while, but I believe it was meant to convey that they were all talk and now they can watch as they others take action.

Comment: @Lady_A: Interesting but either the word was used slightly differently 50+ years ago or it refers specifically to it being used in a cut scene or perhaps, also in a cut scene, Mickey talks noticeably more than other people. My guess is that the word came up during negotiations because actually Mickey was pretty vocal and opposed to Sid's character during that earlier scene and Sid said something like, all u do is filibuster.

Comment: @Lady_A: Just thinking that Mickey may have said that he would filibuster or was filibustering.